# Is it okay to have 100% CPU usage constantly?

Tags: cpu-usage, overheating, lifespan, physical-wear

I often do 3D rendering in the background which consumes 100% of the CPU (I lower the priority of the process so that it does not hinder any tasks I am working on).

My concern/question is whether it is okay to run a computer/laptop with a 100% CPU load constantly.

Could this reduce the lifespan of the system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CPU usage at 100% for several hours](http://superuser.com/questions/185662/cpu-usage-at-100-for-several-hours)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As long as the system is adequately cooled, it won't be a problem. For a laptop, this is a greater concern and you would be well advised to make sure that vents have adequate clearance and that the ambient temperature is kept in check. You'd also want to clean the dust out of the system every so often too. The same routines apply to desktop systems too, but they often have more space for better cooling. Small form factor (SFF) systems and iMacs require care similar to laptops because of their design.

If you can offload rendering to a dedicated system, you might be better off overall, but it's not necessary.

Comment: how would you go about making sure the vents have adequate clearance, keeping the ambient temperature in check and cleaning the dust out of the system?

Answer (score 13):

100% usage is probably the goal of the CPU as it's always working.  The downside is that you can't put any more load on it.

It's OK to run a computer at 100% CPU.  As long as your cooling systems are working, there shouldn't be any problems.  If your cooling systems aren't working, heat will shorten the life of your computer.