# Constant CPU utilization on consumer hardware

Tags: cpu, hardware-failure, cpu-usage

A computer in a manufacturing environment is running software that is in a constant communication loop with a PLC. An artifact of the implimentation is ~20-30% CPU utilization 100% of the time (24/7). Will the constant CPU cycling have an impact on the longevity of this hardware?

Comment: A CPU is designed to be used.  20-30% usage is nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CPU usage at 100% for several hours](http://superuser.com/questions/185662/cpu-usage-at-100-for-several-hours), [What is the impact of running the CPU at 100% for long periods at a time?](http://superuser.com/questions/431309/what-is-the-impact-of-running-the-cpu-at-100-for-long-periods-at-a-time), [Is it ok to have 100% CPU usage constantly](http://superuser.com/questions/294238/is-it-ok-to-have-100-cpu-usage-constantly)

Comment: techie007 - all those questions are about using the CPU at 100%, this is about using the CPU at 20-30%

Comment: @JoeTaylor If 100% CPU usage isn't going to break it, then how would 20-30% usage be any different/worse?  If I come back and asked "If I run my CPU at 27%-42% all day, is it going to damage it?" it'd still be the same question (IMO).

Comment: @techi007 The 100% usage questions are about burst usage, this is about continual usage. Which I consider different. I may be splitting hairs buf I do consider it slightly different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is not really, computers are designed to be used over long spans of time(Example, Google's server, Amazon's servers, your router, etc), though [Is the performance of a CPU affected as it ages?](https://superuser.com/questions/456445/is-the-performance-of-a-cpu-affected-as-it-ages) makes the point that there is SOME wear and tear from the age of the component. Bottom line: Unless your CPU is running very hot, it shouldn't be very limiting on the life span to keep at 30%,