# Is keeping cpu on %100 is dangerous?

Tags: bitcoin, data-mining

I'm a bitcoin miner and my pc unfortunately doesn't support gpu mining (keeps crashing my drivers) so I use cpu mining. However, is keeping my cpu on %100 dangerous?
I have a dell inspiron 3542 with i5-4210U. (1,7 to 2,7 ghz)

Comment: You do understand you would have to mine years on a CPU to even get a percent of a percent of a single bitcoin and that's ONLY if the difficulty remained static and it won't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CPU usage at 100% for several hours](http://superuser.com/questions/185662/cpu-usage-at-100-for-several-hours), [Is it okay to have 100% CPU usage constantly?](http://superuser.com/questions/294238/is-it-okay-to-have-100-cpu-usage-constantly?lq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, but why didn't it show it while i was writing my title? Possible bug.

Comment: The automatic duplicate guessing system is far from perfect, but it's not really "buggy".

Comment: @Ramhound I use ltc + I switched to GPU mining.

Comment: @ardaozkal - Now you only have to mine for 5 years to get a percent of a percent.  GPU mining is useless at this difficulty even for LTC.

Comment: @Ramhound What should I use when mining?

Comment: @ardaozkal - LTC mining has moved to dedicated hardware ( i.e. ASIC hardware ).  The subject is well documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 points...

1. so long as it doesn't overheat it will be fine.

However...

2. It long ago became no longer cost effective to mine on a GPU, long before that on a CPU. In short, your electricity bill will be far higher than the value of the coins mined.

Comment: I already have it open 7/24 :P Same electricity :P ps. running for 3 hrs and no overheat.

Comment: Ticking over isn't the same as running full tilt, as far as the electricity bill goes. Anyhow, wish you luck with it.

Comment: @ardaozkal You're mistaken. Running your pc 24/7 while doing nothing does not have the same wattage usage as running your CPU 100% 24/7. Your electic bills WILL be higher. Alot higher.